# Spinnaker GKE oauth - User's info does not have all required fields

Tags: google-oauth, spinnaker

I'm trying to get my spinnaker interface authenticated using this tutorial:
https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/quickstart/halyard-gke-public/

Prior to the tutorial, spinnaker was confirmed up and running on `http://localhost:9000`.  I have tried the following on `1.3.1`, `1.4.1` and `1.4.2`.

After editing/applying/enabling the google security, I try the login and successfully am challenged with a google login screen.  Upon completing the two-factor auth and I am redirected as expected to `http://localhost:8084/login`, though I receive the following error:

```
{
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "Authentication Failed: User's info does not have all required fields.",
  "status": 401,
  "timestamp": 1506985726074
}
```

Here is a log of my setup steps:

```
kross@halyard:~$ hal config security authn oauth2 edit --provider google \
>     --client-id $CLIENT_ID \
>     --client-secret $CLIENT_SECRET \
>     --user-info-requirements hd=$DOMAIN
+ Get current deployment
  Success
+ Get authentication settings
  Success
+ Edit oauth2 authentication settings
  Success
Problems in default.security:
- WARNING Your UI or API domain does not have override base URLs
  set even though your Spinnaker deployment is a Distributed deployment on a
  remote cloud provider. As a result, you will need to open SSH tunnels against
  that deployment to access Spinnaker.
? We recommend that you instead configure an authentication
  mechanism (OAuth2, SAML2, or x509) to make it easier to access Spinnaker
  securely, and then register the intended Domain and IP addresses that your
  publicly facing services will be using.

+ Successfully edited oauth2 method.
kross@halyard:~$ hal config security authn oauth2 enable
+ Get current deployment
  Success
+ Edit oauth2 authentication settings
  Success
Problems in default.security:
- WARNING Your UI or API domain does not have override base URLs
  set even though your Spinnaker deployment is a Distributed deployment on a
  remote cloud provider. As a result, you will need to open SSH tunnels against
  that deployment to access Spinnaker.
? We recommend that you instead configure an authentication
  mechanism (OAuth2, SAML2, or x509) to make it easier to access Spinnaker
  securely, and then register the intended Domain and IP addresses that your
  publicly facing services will be using.

+ Successfully enabled oauth2

kross@halyard:~$ hal  deploy apply
+ Get current deployment
  Success
+ Apply deployment
  Success
+ Deploy spin-clouddriver
  Success
+ Deploy spin-front50
  Success
+ Deploy spin-orca
  Success
+ Deploy spin-deck
  Success
+ Deploy spin-echo
  Success
+ Deploy spin-gate
  Success
+ Deploy spin-igor
  Success
+ Deploy spin-rosco
  Success
Problems in default.security:
- WARNING Your UI or API domain does not have override base URLs
  set even though your Spinnaker deployment is a Distributed deployment on a
  remote cloud provider. As a result, you will need to open SSH tunnels against
  that deployment to access Spinnaker.
? We recommend that you instead configure an authentication
  mechanism (OAuth2, SAML2, or x509) to make it easier to access Spinnaker
  securely, and then register the intended Domain and IP addresses that your
  publicly facing services will be using.
```

I'm not quite sure what to do with this.  It seems I am authentic, yet for some reason the required user fields are not allowed in the interaction.

I have reviewed [spinnaker's authentication setup](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/security/authentication/) as well and repeatedly made a few changes and tested with a fresh incognito browser, yet no change.

Since the [`google` provider is a packaged OAuth 2 provider with spinnaker](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/security/authentication/oauth/), I'm confused as to what further configuration would be necessary, as I am not "bringing my own provider".

Where can I start looking next?  Any references/pointers to documentation?

Comment: You are required to show the code you are using here: [mcve] Otherwise, anything said is just a wild guess. Links go dead. The link to the tutorial will do no one any good if it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `--user-info-requirements hd=$DOMAIN` argument. This is (generally) only needed if you're using a G Suite/Google Apps for Work account as your OAuth identity provider - it restricts login to only users in your domain. Otherwise, anyone with a valid @gmail account would be able login.

If you do use the `--user-info-requirements hd=$DOMAIN` and the `$DOMAIN` specified is invalid, you will receive this error.  Be sure to use the fully qualified domain name as the value.

Comment: I am a G Suite/Google Apps user and I DO want to restrict it to my domain.  Is your answer that it should be omitted?  Then I would not get restriction based on the domain correct?

Comment: Seems you figured it out. You indeed must use the FQDN: https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker.github.io/issues/363#issuecomment-335881201